# Searching for a matching subslice?

Tags: rust, slice

[`std::String::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.find) searches for a pattern in a `String`, and in particular can search for a substring.

I can't see an equivalent for general slices, or even (as I'm interested in) specifically `&[u8]` or `Vec<u8>`.  Have I missed something obvious?  It seems it would be an even easier thing to provide for `&[u8]` than for `String` when you don't need to worry about UTF-8.  :-)

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster; I tried things like "subslice" but not "subsequence".

Comment: Haha, me too! I *knew* there was a question about it already though, so I eventually found it. Now this question will get the all-important `subslice` keyword for search engines ;-)